# How to always open QComboBox popup downwards?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, qcombobox

I'm using a stylesheet for my GUI elements such as the QComboBox and I need the popup to drop downwards which is not working at all. I'm working on a Linux based system. My Qt version is 5.4.2.

I already tried to set the style of the whole application with `QApplication::setStyle("fusion")` or `QApplication::setStyle("cleanlooks")` which apparently didn't seem to work.

The combobox looks like this:

[image: first item]
[image: second item]

As you can see the popup always covers the actual button but i need it to expand underneath.

I'd appreciate any help on this matter!

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was a style issue. I had to start the application with the `-style cleanlooks` parameter.